# Can we store and fetch call recordings audio files into database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

in what format I have to save audio file in the sqlite database

Comment: No but you can store them in storage and save their path in sqlite.

Comment: okay but if I want to fetch those files. how will i fetch through a database or through their path?

Comment: You can fetch them from storage. In which the path of file will be hold by Database

Comment: I Store audio file like this: 
File  sampleDir = newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/CallRecording");
then as u saud , i stored audio path in db 
voiceDataModel.setPath(String.valueOf(sampleDir));

Comment: Then i fetch that file,
  dbManager.open();
                Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();
                cursor.moveToFirst();

               String filePAth = (cursor.getString(1));

Comment: You will get filepath this way then you have to get the file from path. But make sure if user delete the file remove the entry from Database

Comment: that's the thing in which I'm confused. I get the file path. but how i get the actual audio file from that path through using database

Answer (score 1):

sqlite only support **BLOB** for complex data formats.

You have to insert Audio binary data to sqlite and convert it to correct format while fetching data from sqlite.

**BUT** this action not recommended because of slow functionality of saving and loading big binary data through sqlite .

**IT's RECOMMENDED** to save file with its **Original Format** to Application folder instead for more high performance application .

Comment: **i converted mp3  file to decoded format like this**
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-4.wav");
 byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) sampleDir.length()];
encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);
decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, 0);
**then i save into sqlite in BLOB format** and sqlite shows    [B@8d0eda9
is this correct?

Comment: @KhadijaHameed why are you saving mp3 files in a sqlite table? Just write to the user storage

Comment: [B@8d0eda9 this message means it's object not binary stream. make sure you pass byte[] to sqlite.